# Generating inverse polygons inside polygon

Tags: postgis, postgresql, polygon

I'm designing a PostGIS database with country polygon and many layer polygons of water areas, inside these country polygon. I need to generate inverse polygons to water polygons, that doesn't contain water polygon.

Something like to my question is published there [How to find polygons inside polygon with PostGIS 2.0](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34919/how-to-find-polygons-inside-polygon-with-postgis-2-0). The main question is it real to generate polygons with PostGIS in the main country polygon that doesn't contain water polygons?

Comment: You could consider using *ST_Difference* function: https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Difference.html

Comment: @julien thank you, its may be soltion. I will test it